# Membership provider deployment issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, asp.net-membership, dsn

I am trying to deploy a asp.net mvc site. My hosting service provider provides me dsn database connection for my sql server 2008 database. I changed my web.config to use dsn connection using this modification in web.config.

```
<appSettings>       
        <add key="myDSN" value="evdsn"/>    

</appSettings>
```

In my site I have used asp.net membership provider. I have all the tables of membership provider in my own database. when I deploy the site I get the following error:
\

[image]

My web.config file is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <!--<configSections>

    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>-->
    <appSettings>       
            <add key="myDSN" value="evodsn"/>           
    </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="evocon" connectionString="DSN=myDSN" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>


    <system.web>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
    -->
    <httpHandlers>
      <!--<add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>-->
      <add verb="*" path="TinyMCEHandler.aspx" type="Moxiecode.TinyMCE.Web.HttpHandler, Moxiecode.TinyMCE" validate="false" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="true" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

    <!--<httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>-->

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" /></assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account.mvc/index" timeout="2880" protection="All" />
        </authentication>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear />               
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="evocon" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
                <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.-->

        <customErrors mode="Off">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm"/>
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm"/>
        </customErrors>

        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="System.Linq" />
                <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
                <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>

    </system.web>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="MvcHttpHandler" />
            <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
            <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </handlers>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="Default.php" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.html" />
                <add value="Index.aspx" />
                <add value="Index.asp" />
                <add value="Index.php" />
                <add value="Index.htm" />
                <add value="Index.html" />
                <add value="parking.htm" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
  <!--<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data"/>
  </elmah>-->
  <location path="App_Data" allowOverride="false">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You should post the full config file line that is highlighted in red in the error message.

Comment: good question with lots of info. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying in your `<membership><provider>` node that you want the `connectionStringName` to be "myconnectionstring", yet you don't specify that connection string anywhere.  You've got an AppSetting key, but that isn't being used either.   So, yes, you should use the DSN name provided to you, but you've got to put it in the right place, which is the `connectionStrings` node in your .config file.

**Update**
[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35c54x95%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) article about connecting to an ODBC database via the SQLDataSourceControl has some helpful info, namely, that your connectionString section could look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add 
      name="ODBCDataConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Driver=ODBCDriver;server=ODBCServer;"
      providerName="System.Data.Odbc"
    />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

...so, perhaps instead of using the DSN designation, you could use the "server" attribute of the connectionString and then just use their dsn name there?

Comment: I have updated my web.config file as you suggested but now i am getting error "Keyword not supported: 'dsn'."

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using?  Does the database provider really want you to connect only via ODBC?

Answer (score 1):

What the error message is saying is that in the config file where you specify you'd like to use the `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` provider, you are not specifying a valid connection string, which must be defined in a `connectionStrings` section of your config file.

Comment: yes but what dsn should i give in connectionstring i am already providing the dsn in web.config for my database

Comment: See @Nick's answer.  Putting the DSN name in appSettings means nothing to ASP.NET.  The important part is that in your web.config, you're telling the Membership provider to use a connection string named `myconnectionstring`, and you haven't specified that connection string in the `connectionStrings` section.

Comment: Please see the updated web.config I am getting "Keyword not supported: 'dsn'." error

Comment: Your connection string looks fine, but something occurred to me; the Membership provider you're using is `SqlMembershipProvider`, which only supports SQL Server.  Since your DSN connection uses the .NET framework's ODBC provider, it may not be compatible with SqlMembershipProvider.  Maybe your hosting provider can give you a non-DSN option.  Otherwise, you would have to create your own `MembershipProvider` implementation (not difficult, but not trivial either).

Comment: I think @Jacob is on to something here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this connection string:

System DSN
DSN=myDsn;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=;

File DSN
FILEDSN=c:\myDsnFile.dsn;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=;

From: http://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn